# Angular Button click with Template reference variable is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, button

I have two html buttons in angular application. Not sure what is causing issue.

Stackblitz code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-reference-variable-to-access-svl1kl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

First button is as below: I have button click event on 1st button with template reference variable

```
<button (click)="accessButton(b)" #b >Click me!</button>
```

Second button is as below:
Problem:I have focusout event and want to set the focus to 1st button once user click on tab when the focus is on 2nd button. But for some reason template reference variable is getting error to set focus to first button.

```
<button (click)="onYes()" (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)" [disabled]="isDisabled">Yes</button>
```

Typescript file:

```
@ContentChild('onNo', { static: false }) elOnNo: ElementRef;
  accessButton(b) {
    alert('click');
  }

  onFocusOut($event) {
    this.elOnNo.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting an HTML element that has `#elementId` you'll have to use

`@ViewChild('elementId', {static: false}) element: ElementRef`

In your case that would be.

`@ViewChild('b', {static: false}) elOnNo: ElementRef`

Also in your StackBlitz example some methods that are called seem to be missing.
[image]

Here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for `@ViewChild`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. My requirement is to set focus to 'No' button after user click on TAB button when focus is on Yes button. If user click on TAB again then focus will be going to Yes button automatically as it is next button in the sequence. Here is my updated stackblitz code. Please check here.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-reference-variable-to-access-epfsqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The example still uses `@ContentChild` which doesn't work.

As I stated in my answer, please replace `@ContentChild` with `@ViewChild`

Comment: To focus the "No" button using TAB you can either use the attribute `tabindex` or use the event `(keydown.tab)=focusNoButton()`